# Generate Binary Sequence

Tags: c

I want to generate  permutations of string of 5 0s followed by the permutations of 4 0s and a single 1, followed by the permutations of 3 0s with 2 1s etc? My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int i,j,k,l,s[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  s[i]=0;
for(k=0;k<5;k++)
       printf("%d  ",s[k]);
   printf("\n");
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    if(i==j)
      s[j]=1;

    else
      s[j]=0;
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
       printf("%d  ",s[k]);
   printf("\n");
                 }
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(k=0;k<5;k++)
    s[k]=0;
  s[i]=1;
  for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
    s[j]=1;
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
       printf("%d  ",s[k]);
    printf("\n");
    for(k=j;k<5;k++)
       s[k]=0;
                    }

                 }

printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){

  for(j=i+1;j<5;j++){
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
       s[k]=0;
    s[i]=1;
    s[j]=1;
    for(l=j+1;l<5;l++){
        s[l]=1;
    for(k=0;k<5;k++)
       printf("%d  ",s[k]);
    printf("\n");
    for(k=l;k<5;k++)
       s[k]=0;
                      }
                    }

                 }


}
```

**So output is**

```
0  0  0  0  0  
---------------------------------------------
1  0  0  0  0  
0  1  0  0  0  
0  0  1  0  0  
0  0  0  1  0  
0  0  0  0  1  
---------------------------------------------
1  1  0  0  0  
1  0  1  0  0  
1  0  0  1  0  
1  0  0  0  1  
0  1  1  0  0  
0  1  0  1  0  
0  1  0  0  1  
0  0  1  1  0  
0  0  1  0  1  
0  0  0  1  1  
---------------------------------------------
1  1  1  0  0  
1  1  0  1  0  
1  1  0  0  1  
1  0  1  1  0  
1  0  1  0  1  
1  0  0  1  1  
0  1  1  1  0  
0  1  1  0  1  
0  1  0  1  1  
0  0  1  1  1
```

Output is ok. However in my code I use
different for loops for different cases. 
Is it possible to use better approach so
that length of the code is reduced?

Comment: Hint: try to count in binary and think about how you can use operators like `&` and `|` (**and** and **or** respectively) to generated those permutations.

Comment: Another approach would be to write a routine that generates permutations of an array of things, like an array of ints. You can find many examples on the web of permutation functions that you could adapt (e.g., http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) Then call that on `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, `{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, etc.

Comment: Seeking improvements to working code goes on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RaymondChen does that mean any SSCCE should go to codereview? ;)

Comment: @WayneUroda If the code works but needs improvement, then codereview. If the code doesn't work, then SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach follows.  This solution needs O(n) space and each output string requires O(n) time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *buf;

// Print combinations of m 1's in a field of n 0/1's starting at s.
void print_combinations(char *s, int n, int m)
{
  // If there is nothing left to append, we are done.  Print the buffer.
  if (m == 0 && n == 0) {
    *s = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return;
  }
  // Cut if there are more 1's than positions left or negative numbers.
  if (m > n || m < 0 || n < 0) return;
  // Append a 0 and recur to print the rest.
  *s = '0';
  print_combinations(s + 1, n - 1, m);
  // Now do the same with 1.
  *s = '1';
  print_combinations(s + 1, n - 1, m - 1);
}

int main(void)
{  
  int n = 5;
  buf = malloc(n + 1);
  for (int m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
    print_combinations(buf, n, m);
    printf("-----\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Until you try it with n = 8k + 1 ;-)

Comment: Of course yes. You could make buf local to main and size it automatically.

Comment: Your comments at the top here are correct, I just fixed my answer. I am not offended, but I think the correct place for such comments would be on my answer. I also think it is probably more polite to say in your answer "my code uses O(n)..." rather than calling me out explicitly. I'm not hurt though :)

Comment: Note that this problem can be solved without recursion at all. (For extra credit, presumably.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive function like so - you don't have to print the result when finished, you could add it to a list etc.

The function works by starting with an empty string. At each step you add one more character - in this case you add either a `0` or a `1`.

If a `1` is added we account for this by decrementing the `ones` value on the next call to the function. (In a more general case you could pass a list of all the elements to be permuted - then the process would be to pick from this list, add it to your permutation and remove it from the list. You repeat that until the list is empty and you have permuted all of the elements in the list.)

When the string reaches the desired length we have finished and so we return.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recurse(char *str, int length, int maxLength, int ones)
{
    if (length == maxLength)
    {
        // we are finished
        printf("%s\n", str);
        return;
    }

    if (ones > 0)
    {
        // put a 1 into the new string
        str[length] = '1';
        recurse(str, length + 1, maxLength, ones - 1);
    }

    if (ones < maxLength - length)
    {
        // there are still spaces for 0s
        // put a 0 into the string
        str[length] = '0';
        recurse(str, length + 1, maxLength, ones);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int maxLength = 5;
    char buffer[maxLength + 1];
    buffer[maxLength] = 0;

    int ones;
    for (ones = 0; ones <= maxLength; ones++)
    {
        printf("Ones: %i\n", ones);
        recurse(buffer, 0, maxLength, ones);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Ones: 0
00000

Ones: 1
10000
01000
00100
00010
00001

Ones: 2
11000
10100
10010
10001
01100
01010
01001
00110
00101
00011

Ones: 3
11100
11010
11001
10110
10101
10011
01110
01101
01011
00111

Ones: 4
11110
11101
11011
10111
01111

Ones: 5
11111
```

Finally, unless you really want to/need to learn/use C, I would recommend using C++ because you get really nice features like `std::vector` and `std::set` and so many other things which will make your life so much easier. I would have written this completely different in C++.